# variable is undefined in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
type User ={
    id: number;
    name?: string;
    nickname?: string;
}

type Info = {
    id: number;
    city?: string;
}

type SuperUser = User & Info;

let su:SuperUser;
su.id = 1; 

console.log(su);
```

This is a simple code. I did try the intersection types.Why console return me 'su' is undefined?

Comment: Where do you think you set a *value* for `su`? `let su: SuperUser;` only sets a *type*, the *value* is `undefined`.

Comment: @johnsharpe : sorry I did not pay attention to the ```type``` keyword. Comment deleted

Comment: @jonrsharpe I do su.id = 1;

Comment: And that's what's *triggering* the TypeError.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can u give me the solution? please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign some values to your variable first otherwise it would be `undefined` like this:

```
type User ={
    id: number;
    name?: string;
    nickname?: string;
}

type Info = {
    id: number;
    city?: string;
}

type SuperUser = User & Info;

let su:SuperUser = { // <-- First we assign some value
    id: 1
};
su.id = 2; // <-- and then we can use or change the value

console.log(su);
```

try on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvAbwFBW1AlgEwC4oA7AVwFsAjJAbixxIEMKIB%20YuYRXEgc3o5SuAMYBrZqw5QuPfvQC%20GDKEhQAkiQBmAe1RRMQgsXLU6DbCNyhps3gIxKV4aAGUykRPCT7vyAGQa2jr0GAA2EMAyZITunn76hjjGUACMjspwZAB0BPoATMoiOiRwOhHZYTp8ABRZAJS0QA)